# Можно ли в mysql установить primary key на несколько столбцов, среди которых есть строковые?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не будет ли слишком тормозить обработка таблицы, в которой на 1 числовой (tinyint unsigned) и 4 строковых столбца (varchar(8)) поставлен primary key?

Ситуация такова: в базе mysql с кодировкой utf8mb4 нужно хранить векторы с пятью координатами. Первая координата числовая, для неё предусмотрен столбец типа tinyint unsigned. Остальные 4 столбца могут быть или натуральными числами, или же строками (длиной от 0 до 7-8 символов, а в среднем - 3 символа) такого вида: "45-1-2" (дефис, если есть, лишь *между* натуральными числами).

Каждый вектор уникален, т.е. повторов векторов нет. У каждого вектора есть дополнительные свойства (например, дата добавления в таблицу), для которых предусмотрены поля в таблице.

В таблицу предполагается лишь добавление векторов (не часто: 1-2 в день), удаление (тоже изредка) и поиск нужных векторов по координатам (это уже частая операция). Например, выбрать все векторы, у которых первые три координаты равны фиксированным заданным значениям.

Объём таблицы - не более ста тысяч записей, если смотреть на перспективу :) А реально - до 20-30 тысяч.

Внесение суррогатного ключа я рассматривал, но как-то это кажется бессмысленным, ведь никаких внешних связей таблица не имеет, а для внутренней работы этот ключ не нужен.

Поэтому и возникает вопрос - допусти́м ли такой подход к формированию таблицы?

Comment: При 100к записей, размере записи в 33 байта (т.е. при объёме таблицы несколько метров) и интенсивности изменения менее десятка операций по изменению в день можно вообще не задумываться об описанных мелочах. Ну разве что "поиск нужных векторов по координатам (это уже частая операция)" - это более тысячи запросов в секунду.. *допусти́м ли такой подход к формированию таблицы?* Да.

Comment: @Akina спасибо. Более тысячи запросов на чтение в секунду точно не будет :) Максимум - 10 запросов, но это в самом крайнем случае. Я верно понимаю, что, например, для строки "45-2" потребуется не 32 байта, а 4, несмотря на указание кодировки в utf8?

Comment: 10 запросов в секунду? это ни о чём.. *Я верно понимаю, что, например, для строки "45-2" потребуется не 32 байта, а 4, несмотря на указание кодировки в utf8?* Да. Если поле NOT NULL. https://dbfiddle.uk/mfPFSsKE